Is there a standard or method for creating multiple, separate, batch NFT mints within one contract or deployment?
Is there a standard or method for creating multiple, separate, batch mints NFT within one contract or deployment? While each Batch maintain its own unique metadata? For example, say i need, 6 different NFT's, each with their own metadata, but i also need 300 copies of the same NFT's to be able to be dispersed to holders and each one remain unique from the other 299 in terms of ownership and "usage" of the asset.
So 6 stacks of NFT. A, B, C, D, E, F, and i need a,b,c,d,etc to all be unique, different NFT. But NFT "A:1-300" are identical, and holder "A" can use NFT "A:1" at same instant Holder "B" is using NFT "A:143" while holding and using NFT "C-36". if that makes sense....is there any specific token standard or contract type to be able to create and deploy all of that mint information in a single mint/transaction/deployment to the blockchain?

Checkout ERC1155, this is a multitoken standard developed by Enjin Game development.
In this standard each token ID can have one or more than one tokens. Check the implementation for better understanding.
